# How does a homotopy $f\simeq g$ induces a homotopy equivalence between their mapping toruses $M_f$ and $M_g$?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

By a mapping torus $M_f$ of a continuous map $f:X\to X$ we mean the space $$X\times I/\{(x,0)\sim (f(x),1)\}.$$

Now given $f,g:X\to X$ and $F:X\times I\to X$ with $F(x,0)=f(x)$ and $F(x,1)=g(x)$, namely $F$ a homotopy between $f$ and $g$, then how does $F$ induce a homotopy equivalence $\bar F:M_f\to M_g$?

I came up with the map defined by $M_f\ni(x,t)\mapsto (F(x,t),t)\in M_g$, which is a well-defined continuous map from $M_f$ to $M_g$, but I'm having difficulties showing that it is a homotopy equivalence. A natural inverse of this map is given by $M_g\ni (x,t)\mapsto (F(x,1-t),t)\in M_f$, but I don't think their composition is homotopic to the identity, so possiblely I just came up with a wrong map.

Any hint or solution is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Lemma: Let $A\subseteq X$ be a cofibration and $f\simeq g:A\rightarrow Y$ homotopic maps. Then the adjunction spaces $X\cup_fY$ and $X\cup_gY$ are homotopy equivalent.

This is Proposition 0.18 on pg. 16 of Hatcher's *Algebraic Topology*. The statement is for a CW pair $(X,A)$, but you'll notice that the proof only requires the subspace $A\subseteq X$ to have the homotopy extension property.

Now, to use the lemma we recognise the mapping torus of $f:X\rightarrow X$ as the pushout of the span

$$X\times I\xleftarrow{i_0+i_1}X\sqcup X\xrightarrow{id_X+f}X$$

where $i_a:X\hookrightarrow X\times I$ for $a=0,1$ is the inclusion $i_a(x)=(x,a)$. The left-pointing arrow above is a cofibration since it is the pushout product of the two cofibrations $\emptyset\hookrightarrow X$ and $\partial I\hookrightarrow I$. A homotopy $f\simeq g$ induces a homotopy of $id_X\sqcup f\simeq id_X\sqcup g$, and we apply the lemma to get a homotopy equivalence $M_f\simeq M_g$.

Comment: Thanks! This is clear enough for me even though I don't really know about pushout product. When $X$ is a CW-complex, then $X\sqcup X$ is a subcomplex of $X\times I$ and satisfies the homotopy extension property automatically. By now I need only consider the case when $X$ is a CW-complex.

Comment: @Shana, what I mean by the 'pushout product' is this: if $A\hookrightarrow X$ and $B\hookrightarrow Y$ are cofibrations, and at least one is closed, then $(A\times Y)\cup (X\times B)\hookrightarrow X\times Y$ is a cofibration. I couldn't see this statement in Hatcher although it is standard.

Comment: Thanks. Actually I searched for it and saw an explanation on nLab in categorical language. But I still don't know why the pushout product is a cofibration. I don't even know whether $A\times B\hookrightarrow X\times Y$ is a cofibration...Each silice $A\times \{y_0\}\hookrightarrow X\times \{y_0\}$ is a cofibration but there seems no guarantee that putting the extension for each slice together gives continuous maps.

Comment: It's not true for arbitrary cofibrations - at least one must be closed. It's a non-trivial (but not difficult) result that doesn't follow from the axioms (it's not true in arbitrary model categories). To prove it exhibit the inclusion $A\subseteq X$ as an NDR pair (see https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/neighborhood+retract) and use the data to construct the required functions to do the same for $(A\times Y)\cup(X\times B)\subseteq X\times Y$,

Comment: To prove that $A\times B\subseteq X\times Y$ is a cofibration, take pushout products with $\emptyset\hookrightarrow X$ and $\emptyset\hookrightarrow Y$, and then use the fact that composites of cofibrations are cofibrations.

Comment: Do you mean that at least one of $A$ and $B$ must be closed in $X$, $Y$ respectively by "at least one must be closed"? I still don't see a clue of proving this. Maybe I'd better let it be by now and look back at this as I study further. Thank you anyway.

Comment: A cofibration is an embedding. It's often said to be *closed* if it has closed image. The closed cofibrations tend to be nicer to work with and have better formal properties than their non-closed counterparts. Hatcher doesn't go into much detail about cofibrations. A book I like which does (which is still fairly introductory) is Jeff Strom's book *Modern Classical Homotopy Theory* pt. 2, chptr 5.